# Программа: "у попа была собака..."

Tags: c

Совсем недавно начал изучать "C". Ради интереса решил написать программу, реализующую бесконечный (или почти бесконечный) цикл. В итоге вот что написал:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char str[10];
    int n = 0;
    printf("spet pesenku?n");
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '/0'; i++)
        scanf("%s", str[i]);
    if (str == "da") {
        for (int m = 0; m <= 100; m++)
            printf("U popa bila sobaka, on ee lubil.n Ona sela kusok myasa on ee ubil.n V zemlu zakopal, nadpis napisal:n");
        return 0;
    } else
        printf("okayn");
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор ошибок не выявил, но при выполнении во время ввода строки "str" работа программы прекращается. (Прошу помочь найти ошибки, или другие способы решения.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартные C-строки принято сравнивать методом `strcmp(char* a, char* b)`. Почему вы не хотите юзать стандартные I/O потоки С++?

```
char str[10];
printf("spet pesenku?n");
cin.getline(str, 10);
if (strcmp("da", str) == 0) {
    for (int m = 0; m <= 1; m++)
        printf("U popa bila sobaka, on ee lubil.n Ona sela kusok myasa on ee ubil.n V zemlu zakopal, nadpis napisal:n");
    return 0;           // это здесь необязательно...
} else
    printf("okayn");
return 0;
```

Comment: Если уж идти С++-путем, то надо std::string юзать.

Comment: Ну ТС для начала и этого, думаю, хватит)

Comment: Работа с std::string намного проще, чем с Си-строками

Comment: Естественно. Тем более, если считать, что си-строки были оставлены лишь для совместимости...

Comment: Почему никто не отвечает на **вопрос**, а именно про ошибку:

 **при выполнении во время ввода строки "str" работа программы прекращается.** ?

Все начинаю учить *правильно писать на C++*. Однако, фундаментальное непонимание темы автором останется и проявится в других местах.

Answer (score 3):

Вашу идею с циклом

```
for (int i=0; str[i]!='/0';i++)
            scanf("%s", str[i]);
```

совершенно не понял (IMHO это бред), но ошибка заключается в записи **str[i]** в  scanf() с форматом "%s". Аргументом (переменой)  для этого формата должен быть ***адрес***, начиная с которого разместить прочитанное слово.

Если Вы хотите прочитать байты в массив char str[] с позиции i, то надо писать

```
scanf("%s",str+i); или scanf("%s",&str[i]);
```

Вы же передаете в функцию scanf() "грязь" (4  байта (для 64-bit машины 8)), *которая находится* ***по адресу*** *i-го байта* в массиве str.

Answer (score 1):

Подумайте вот об этой строчке

```
if (str=="da")
```

Comment: else okay =)